# C++ const char to char

Tags: c++, массивы

имею структуру

```
struct tree
{
    char name[9];
    int count;
};
```

при попытке определить ее в main

```
tree.name= "12345678";
```

Выходит ошибка

```
error C2440: =: невозможно преобразовать 'const char [9]' в 'char [9]'
    введите сюда код
```

Присваивал так же с помощью символов '1','2','3' и тд ошибка

```
 error C2440: =: невозможно преобразовать 'char' в 'char [9]'
```

Создавал отдельно массив размеров [9] и присваивал его, но была ошибка

```
error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: константа
error C2106: =: левый операнд должен быть левосторонним значением
```

Как же все таки сделать чтоб присвоить и программа не ругалась?

Comment: Зачем вам С++, если у вас код сишный? Да и `tree` это тип, а не переменная.

Comment: Почитайте заодно о том, что такое [mcve] и как его привести в вопросе.

Comment: struct tree { char* name; int count; }; int main () {tree t; t.name = "13455"; /*etc*/return 0;}

Answer (score 6):

Массивы непосредственно не присваиваются!

Вот так - другое дело:

```
strcpy(tree.name,"12345678");
```

Answer (score 3):

В своем вопросе вы говорите о каком-то "определении", но в коде никакого определения не видно.

Если бы вы действительно делали определение объекта типа `tree`

```
tree t;
```

то в таком определении вы могли бы указать инициализатор

```
tree t = { "12345678" };
```

или сделать то же самое через через присваивание

```
t = { "12345678" };
```

Однако в обоих случаях инициализируется/присваивается весь объект, а не отдельное поле, т.е. происходит обнуление `t.count`.

Присвоить отдельный голый массив нельзя. Либо используйте `std::strcpy`, либо замените `char name[9];` на `std::array<char, 9>` (или даже на `std::string`)

```
struct tree
{
    std::array<char, 9> name;
    int count;
};
...
t.name = { "12345678" };
```

---

Clang принимает просто

```
t = { "12345678" };
```

а GCC - нет. В GCC требуется

```
t = tree{ "12345678" };
```

Очевидно прав Clang (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555026/initializing-stdarraychar-x-member-in-constructor-using-string-literal-gcc)

Comment: Если память критична , то лучше  std::array<char, 9>

Answer (score 0):

Если вы напишете  так:

```
struct tree
{
    char name[9] = "12345";
    int count;
};
```

То  здесь  `char name[9] = "123445";` является определением массива. Это не будет ошибкой.  Но  вот  `tree().name = "12345"`, это уже присваивание, что уже невозможно выполнить (скобки для вызова конструктора)